# How to use automapper with different properties names?

Tags: c#, automapper

I am trying to use Automapper on properties with different names.
Is there a better way to do this than to individually map each property to another?

```
public class User
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}

public class bruker
{
     public string navn { get; set; }
     public int alder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, have you actually Googled (or Binged) your title? You may be interested ;)

Comment: You would be better off if the property names of the target and destination objects were identical that is where time is really saved.

Comment: @lrb: well yeah obviously, but the entire question is what to do if that isn't the case.

Comment: Thanks for every one. i show only an example. in my case i have a more than 50 different properties.

Comment: without useing following line in 50 times. how can i do this .thank you Mapper.CreateMap<User, Bruker>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.name, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.navn));

Comment: The "duplicates" are all about the alternative the OP clearly states not to aim at. This is about a kind of global mapping, as in `navn` will always, anywhere be mapped to `Name`. Not that I think AutoMapper can do this, but it's a different question. Voting to reopen.